# Transaction w/ invalid nonce

Tags: web3js, javascript

Web3.js throws an error "Transaction w/ invalid nonce." when I try to call contract methods from JavaScript console. 
The same methods from the same contracts work fine from Mist, or, what is strange when I 'geth attach' to geth started by Mist - web3.js works with the same mehtods, but on 'pure' Mist - not. 
It's not a problem of Mist, I tried the same wit geth on the server without Mist.

For example:

I have a contract on https://etherscan.io/address/0x80f84866d4872f1ea412ddf10e2ed7af0b8ca8fb

Contract code: https://etherscan.io/address/0x80f84866d4872f1ea412ddf10e2ed7af0b8ca8fb#code

In JavaScript console I have a contract object ProofOfExistence (web3.eth.contract -  https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract ). When I try to call contact function from JavaScript console using web3.js I get an error like this:

```
Transaction w/ invalid nonce. tx=0  state=3)
```

web3.eth.getTransactionCount(web3.eth.accounts[0]) returns 3

I tried (https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods):

```
ProofOfExistence.docIndex();
```

or

```
ProofOfExistence.docIndex({nonce: web3.eth.getTransactionCount(web3.eth.accounts[0])});
```

or

```
ProofOfExistence.docIndex.call();
```

or

```
ProofOfExistence.docIndex.call({nonce: web3.eth.getTransactionCount(web3.eth.accounts[0])});
```

with the same error: Transaction w/ invalid nonce. tx=0  state=3)

How to access contract methods from web3.js to avoid this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This 'Transaction w/ invalid nonce' was a problem on Geth/v1.5.0-unstable/linux/go1.5.1

On Geth/v1.4.9-stable/linux/go1.5.1  works fine.

The solution:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove ethereum geth # Geth/v1.5.0-unstable/linux/go1.5.1
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:ethereum/ethereum-dev # Geth/v1.5.0-unstable/linux/go1.5.1 
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ethereum # Geth/v1.4.9-stable/linux/go1.5.1
```