# How i can access the contract functions (After run compiling the contract source code)

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment, greeter

I run the following simple contract

```
var greeterSource = 'contract mortal { address owner; function mortal() { owner = msg.sender; } function kill() { if (msg.sender == owner) selfdestruct(owner); } } contract greeter is mortal { string greeting; function greeter(string _greeting) public { greeting = _greeting; } function greet() constant returns (string) { return greeting; } }'

var greeterCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(greeterSource)

var _greeting = "Hello World!"
var greeterContract = web3.eth.contract(greeterCompiled.greeter.info.abiDefinition);

var greeter = greeterContract.new(_greeting,{from:web3.eth.accounts[0], data: greeterCompiled.greeter.code, gas: 300000}, function(e, contract){
if(!e) {

  if(!contract.address) {
    console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");

  } else {
    console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
    console.log(contract);
  }

}
else
{
  console.log(e);
}
})
```

and get the following output

```
Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: 0xd4b3b0e627e54d0c847fe4379a910b5a4cbc883269d88e6964a68e6e6042f30c waiting to be mined...
Contract mined! Address: 0x06b805ac3b28faed4560f2c4a01b1f988644df12
{ _eth: 
   { _requestManager: { provider: [Object], polls: {}, timeout: null },
 getBalance: { [Function] request: [Function], call: 'eth_getBalance' },
     getStorageAt: { [Function] request: [Function], call: 'eth_getStorageAt' },
     getCode: { [Function] request: [Function], call: 'eth_getCode' },
     getBlock: { [Function] request: [Function], call: [Function] },
     getUncle: { [Function] request: [Function], call: [Function] },
     getCompilers: { [Function] request: [Function], call: 'eth_getCompilers' },
     getBlockTransactionCount: { [Function] request: [Function], call: [Function] },
     getBlockUncleCount: { [Function] request: [Function], call: [Function] },
     getTransaction: { [Function] request: [Function], call: 'eth_getTransactionByHash' },
     getTransactionFromBlock: { [Function] request: [Function], call: [Function] },
     getTransactionReceipt: { [Function] request: [Function], call: 'eth_getTransactionReceipt' },
     getTransactionCount: { [Function] request: [Function], call: 'eth_getTransactionCount' },
     call: { [Function] request: [Function], call: 'eth_call' },
     estimateGas: { [Function] request: [Function], call: 'eth_estimateGas' },
     sendRawTransaction: { [Function] request: [Function], call: 'eth_sendRawTransaction' },
     sendTransaction: { [Function] request: [Function], call: 'eth_sendTransaction' },
     sign: { [Function] request: [Function], call: 'eth_sign' },
     compile: { solidity: [Object], lll: [Object], serpent: [Object] },
     submitWork: { [Function] request: [Function], call: 'eth_submitWork' },
     getWork: { [Function] request: [Function], call: 'eth_getWork' },
     coinbase: [Getter],
     getCoinbase: { [Function] request: [Function] },
     mining: [Getter],
     getMining: { [Function] request: [Function] },
     hashrate: [Getter],
     getHashrate: { [Function] request: [Function] },
     syncing: [Getter],
     getSyncing: { [Function] request: [Function] },
     gasPrice: [Getter],
     getGasPrice: { [Function] request: [Function] },
     accounts: [Getter],
     getAccounts: { [Function] request: [Function] },
     blockNumber: [Getter],
     getBlockNumber: { [Function] request: [Function] },
     iban: 
      { [Function]
        fromAddress: [Function],
        fromBban: [Function],
        createIndirect: [Function],
        isValid: [Function] },
     sendIBANTransaction: [Function] },
  transactionHash: '0xd4b3b0e627e54d0c847fe4379a910b5a4cbc883269d88e6964a68e6e6042f30c',
  address: '0x06b805ac3b28faed4560f2c4a01b1f988644df12',
  abi: 
   [ { constant: false,
       inputs: [],
       name: 'kill',
       outputs: [],
       type: 'function' },
     { constant: true,
       inputs: [],
       name: 'greet',
       outputs: [Object],
       type: 'function' },
     { inputs: [Object], type: 'constructor' } ],
  kill: 
   { [Function]
     request: [Function],
     call: [Function],
     sendTransaction: [Function],
     estimateGas: [Function],
     getData: [Function],
     '': [Circular] },
  greet: 
   { [Function]
     request: [Function],
     call: [Function],
     sendTransaction: [Function],
     estimateGas: [Function],
     getData: [Function],
     '': [Circular] },
  allEvents: [Function] }
```

Now how can i access the functions please give guide to me

I run this line on terminal and geth console but i got the error

```
greeter.greet();
```

the error is

```
ReferenceError: 'greeter' is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13
```

So please help anyone to fix this problem 
if i do anything wrong please mention it

or give the example link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem solved by the version changing of the geth
Please see the below link

[Transaction w/ invalid nonce](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6957/transaction-w-invalid-nonce)

Thank you guyz

Answer (score 1):

That callback is being called twice, the first time when you send the creation contract transaction and the second when the contract is actually mined and has an address (when the else fires in the callback function).

You must wait to the logs to appear stating your contract has been mined and has an address. The [tutorial](https://www.ethereum.org/greeter) says you should wait like a minute, but it really depends on the kind of network you're deploying to: in a private testnet can be faster than in the real ethereum network. Before being mined, your contract is not in the blockchain, so you can't interact with it (and the client side greeter var doesn't have the contract methods yet).

Just check if greet() is a function of greeter before the call to be sure you can actually call it.

If you're just starting with ethereum, I suggest to get an eye on [Testrpc](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc)

Comment: where i need to run the greet function terminal ? or geth console? or in js file . And  can i integrate the multisignature by using https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc. Please give the suggestion. Now i am going to the contract method for multisignature process but i can't run this contract simple example. if the multisignature possible in Testrpc method it will help to me

Comment: web3.js is a javascript component intended to be used on the browser (you can also use it as nodejs component), but geth console also expose a web3.js object. When your contract is deployed, both browser web3 and geth web3 should be able to interact to the contract at the proper address. Keep in mind, however, that if you make a development test using testrpc, you must use testrpc, and no geth, as your rpc web3 provider. I have no experience with testrpc and multisig but testrpc is an ethereum simulator, so it should work